# Prove triangular inequality of the norm in space C'[0,1]

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces

Good day, I need see that if f is in C'[0,1], then $\left \| f \right \|=\left ( \int_{0}^{1}\left ( |f(t)|^2+|f{}'(t)|^2 \right ) dt \right )^{1/2}$ is norm.

Really I have trouble only with the triangular inequality, or can be it equivalent with other norm?

Answer (score 0):

This is basically just repeatedly applying the usual triangle inequality and using that fact that $\int f + g = \int f + \int g$ (integration is a linear operation).

It's easier to square both sides so that you don't have to deal with the square root.

> ${\lVert f(g) + g(t) \rVert}^2 = \int_0^1 (\lvert {f(t) + g(t)}\rvert)^2 + (\lvert{f'(t) + g'(t)}\rvert)^2 dt$
>
> $= \int_{0}^{1} \lvert (f(t))^2 + 2f(t)g(t) + (g(t))^2 \rvert dt + \int_{0}^{1} \lvert (f'(t))^2 + 2f'(t)g'(t) + (g'(t))^2 \rvert dt $
>
> $\leq \int_{0}^{1} {\lvert (f(t)) \rvert}^2 + \lvert 2f(t)g(t) \rvert + \lvert (g(t))^2 \rvert dt + \int_{0}^{1} \lvert (f'(t))^2 \rvert + \lvert 2f'(t)g'(t) \rvert + {\lvert (g'(t)) \rvert}^2 dt$
>
> $= \int_{0}^{1} {\lvert (f(t)) \rvert}^2 dt + \int_{0}^{1} {\lvert (f'(t)) \rvert}^2 dt + \int_0^1 \lvert 2f(t)g(t) \rvert dt + \int_0^1 \lvert 2f'(t)g'(t) \rvert dt + \int_0^1 {\lvert (g(t)) \rvert}^2 dt  + \int_0^1 {\lvert (g'(t)) \rvert}^2 dt$
>
> $= \int_{0}^{1} {\lvert (f(t)) \rvert}^2 + {\lvert (f'(t)) \rvert}^2 dt + \int_0^1 \lvert 2f(t)g(t) \rvert + \lvert 2f'(t)g'(t) \rvert dt + \int_0^1 {\lvert (g(t)) \rvert}^2 + {\lvert (g'(t)) \rvert}^2 dt$
>
> $= {\lVert f(t) \rVert}^2 + 2({\lVert f(t)g(t) \rVert}^2) + {\lVert g(t) \rVert}^2$
>
> $=({\lVert f(t) \rVert + \lVert g(t) \rVert)}^2$

Comment: if you expand the penultimate file is different of the previous, not?

Comment: Yes, I was going too fast and didn't catch that! Thank you. I think I fixed it though.